# Solve $(5+2\sqrt{6})^{x^2-3}+(5-2\sqrt{6})^{x^2-3}=10$

Tags: proof-explanation, exponential-function, quadratics, substitution

> Find the real values of $x$ which satisfy the equation $(5+2\sqrt{6})^{x^2-3}+(5-2\sqrt{6})^{x^2-3}=10$

**My Attempt**
$$
e^{10}=e^{(5+2\sqrt{6})^{x^2-3}+(5-2\sqrt{6})^{x^2-3}}=e^{(5+2\sqrt{6})^{x^2-3}}\cdot e^{(5-2\sqrt{6})^{x^2-3}}=\bigg[e^{(5+2\sqrt{6})}\cdot e^{(5-2\sqrt{6})}\bigg]^{x^2-3}\\
=\Big[e^{10}\Big]^{x^2-3}=e^{10(x^2-3)}\\
\implies x^2-3=1\implies x=\pm2
$$
But my reference gives the solutions $x=\pm2,\pm\sqrt{2}$. Why am I missing the solutions $\pm\sqrt{2}$ in my attempt ?

Comment: Note that $(a^b)^c\neq a^{(b^c)}$, so the last equality on your first line is incorrect.

Comment: One correct way to solve this equation is to call $t= (5+2 \sqrt 6)^{x^2-3}$. Then you get the equation $$t+ \frac{1}{t}=10$$ and proceed from there.

Comment: Put $a=(5+2\sqrt6)^{x^2-3},b=(5-2\sqrt6)^{x^2-3}$ then $a+b=10$ and $ab=1$

Comment: $a^{(b^c)} \ne (a^b)^c$ so you can't say $e^{(a^y)}*e^{(b^y)}=(e^a*e^b)^y$.  It's a coincidence that you got $x=\pm 2$ correctly.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202078/solve-sqrt52-sqrt6x-sqrt5-2-sqrt6x-10

Comment: @fleablood i think thats the reason why I didn't notice that mistake. Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third step is wrong:
$$a^{b^x}\neq\left(a^b\right)^x.$$

Let $(5+2\sqrt6)^{x^2-3}=t$.

Thus, $t^2-10t+1=0,$ which gives $t\in\{5+\sqrt{24},5-2\sqrt6\}$.

Thus, $x^2-3=1$ or $x^2-3=-1.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that $$(5+2\sqrt{6})(5-2\sqrt{6})=1$$